# Filter an array of objects using the filter method with multiple tests

Tags: javascript

I'd like to filter an array of objects based on multiple tests. For this example, I want to filter an array of objects if the values for the keys aren't null, and that one value for one key is less than 90. I'm currently doing this with a for loop like so:

```
let filtered = []
for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    if (articles[i].title !== null && articles[i].title.length <= 90 &&
        articles[i].date !== null &&
        articles[i].image !== null &&
        articles[i].description !== null &&
        articles[i].link !== null) {
        filtered.push(articles[i])
    }
}
```

But it's pretty clumpy and I know the `filter` method can achieve something similar. But I'm unsure if it can check multiple keys and their values with the same test whilst checking if a specific value passes an independent test too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
articles.filter(article => 
  Object.values(article).every(x => (x !== null))
  && article.title.length <= 90
)
```

Let's break this down:

```
articles.filter(article => ...)
```

`.filter` is a function property of type that accepts a [callback argument](https://javascript.info/callbacks), which it calls for each item. Essentially, we're *passing* it a function - not executing it right away, which it can call at its leisure. It's sort of like:

```
let a = alert;
```

We're not calling the `alert` function, we're just saving it to a variable. In the case of `.filter`, we're using it as a pseudo-variable - an argument. Internally, all `.filter` is doing is:

```
Array.prototype.filter(callbackFunc) {
    newArr = [];
    for (i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        if (callbackFunc(this[i]) === false){  // We're calling `callbackFunc` manually, for each item in the loop.
            newArr.push(this[i]);
        }
    }

    return newArr;
}
```

The next bit to explain is the actual callback function we're using. It's defined with ES6 arrow syntax, but it's the equivalent of:

```
articles.filter(function(article){
  return Object.values(article).every(x => (x !== null))
  && article.title.length <= 90
})
```

The first line of the callback function, `Object.values(article).every(x => (x !== null))`, can be broken down to:

```
let values = Object.values(article); // Get the value of all of the keys in the object

function checkFunction(item){ // Define a helper function
    return (x !== null); // Which returns if an item is _not_ null.
}

let result = values.every(checkFunction); // Run `checkFunction` on every item in the array (see below), and ensure it matches _all_ of them.
```

Finally, we just need to clarify what `every` does. It's another example of functional JS, where functions accept callback functions as parameters. The internal code looks like this:

```
Array.prototype.every(callbackFunc) {
    for (i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        if (callbackFunc(this[i]) === false){  // We're calling `callbackFunc` manually, for each item in the loop.
            return false;
        }
    }
    // In JS, returning a value automatically stops execution of the function.
    // So this line of code is only reached if `return false` is never met.
    return true;
}
```

And `&& article.title.length <= 90` should hopefully be self-explanatory: while `.every` returns a boolean value (`true` or `false`), a `true` will only be returned by the callback function to the `filter` if the second condition is **also** met, i.e if the `every` returns `true` **and** `article.title.length <= 90`

Comment: probably the most extendable and cleanest answer! it's a nice one :)

Comment: Why did you use the `some` method rather than `every`?

Comment: I'm working on an explanation now @fellinlovewithaman, I just wanted to FGIW first.

Comment: @fellinlovewithaman oh that's a good catch - based upon your original code, I do think it'd be `every`, since `some` will only need at least one `truthy` value, whereas you want all of them to be `truthy`

Comment: @MatthewLiu true, fixed.

Comment: @fellinlovewithaman I've added an explanation now, hopefully it's a good intro to functional JS!

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` method does exactly this: it takes a conditional (just like that in your `if` statement and adds it to the array if the condition is met. Your code almost matches the `filter` syntax exactly, actually:

```
let filtered = articles.filter(article =>
  article.title !== null
  article.title.length <= 90 &&
  article.date !== null &&
  article.image !== null &&
  article.description !== null &&
  article.link !== null);
```

Answer (score 1):

yes filter can do this, it just takes a function and applies it to each item in the array
`array.filter(x => x.title != null && ... etc)`
the examples in this section is pretty much what you are doing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Filtering_invalid_entries_from_JSON